# DAG does not trigger based on the time specified in the schedule interval

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Let's say the start date is 2022-03-01. I want the DAG to run everyday at 5 am UTC. Here is my DAG:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 3, 1),
    'depends_on_past': False, 
    'email': "xxx@xxx.com",
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'retry': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': "0 5 * * *"
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='airflow_test',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False
)
```

However, this dag would still run at the start of 2022-03-02 instead of 5 am which is specified in the cron expression. Does anyone know what is the potential problem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the schedule interval in your dag object

```
and for your Dictionary you

with DAG(dag_id="dag_1", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *") as dag:
```

try this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Moving `schedule_interval` to the DAG definition might help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html) this is exactly what you specified:

> If you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run with data
> interval starting on 2019-11-21 triggers after 2019-11-21T23:59.
>
> Let’s Repeat That, the scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval
> AFTER the start date, at the END of the interval.
>
> You should refer to DAG Runs for details on scheduling a DAG.

So, in order to run it on the 2022, 3, 1 you could do `datetime(2022, 3, 1) - timedelta(days=1)`